# How are results ordered in solr in a "match all docs" query

Tags: solr, relevance

When I use a "match all docs" query, '`*:*`', asterisk colon asterisk, how are the results ordered?

I presume they get ordered by relevancy, but the relevancy is equal in this case, right? So then, what's the scheme?

Comment: The relevancy is `1.0` for all documents; the result from a `*:*` query on my solr instance starts with words containing `Ek`... It's definitely not ordering on my `id` or `uid` fields, nor any other of the fields; perhaps on some sorted list of n-grams?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When two documents have the same score, Lucene sorts them by index order (the first which has been indexed first) so that running a query twice returns documents in the same order.

Since [MatchAllDocsQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html) gives a constant score to all documents, it returns them in index order.