# Does paging in Solr requires sorting

Tags: solr

In some databases if you don't include sorting in the query, the database may access the same query results each time in different order. So if you are doing paging by sending multiple queries with different start position you may get the same raws multiple times.
Is it the same with Solr?
If I'm iterating all documents by changing the start parameter do I need to include some sorting field?

Comment: Performance gets progressively worse the higher you set the start parameter. If you have millions of documents and want to iterate them all, you should use cursors, as MatsLindh suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documents are by default returned [in the order they're added to the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236774/how-does-solr-sort-by-default-when-using-filter-query). If a document is updated, it's effectively deleted and re-added, so it appears at the end of the index. If you're actually searching (and not just using `fq`), the score will be the same through each page of the result set (and the result set is sorted by score). If the index is updated, the score might change (as you'd expect).

So no, Solr and pagination does not require sorting. If you change the index while paginating, the results will change - just as it would if you sorted on an arbitrary field and added values that lands within the interval you're displaying.

To [use the cursor support](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results) ("cursorMark" or deep paging), you'll have to have the uniqueKey of the collection in the sort (to make the sort deterministic for identical values), but that's not required for queries without a particular sort.