# how to change solr MatchAllDocsQuery order

Tags: solr, lucene

from that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236774/how-does-solr-sort-by-default-when-using-filter-query)  and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310194/how-are-results-ordered-in-solr-in-a-match-all-docs-query) I know that documents are returned in order of their insertion when using [MatchAllDocsQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html)n so that the first document inserted will be the top of results. so my question is how to reverse that order to make the fresh docs in the top.
 thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

it may not be the same as you think , i suggest you in additional to store a timestamp field when inserting data , then order  timestamp field  . It is very accurate  ,  if you don't do this , it may be not correct .

Comment: I think of that possibility, but in my case it not working (I'm not in control of the schema or the indexed data), I find that there is a _docid_ that can do what I'm looking for but, it's not remanded to use it, because it change