# Solr non sorted results order

Tags: solr

I was wondering if I can count on the results order of Solr queries if the queries were not sorted.
For example:
Lets assume there are 100 documents and I want to provide paging by running 10 queries of 10 docs each, where I increment the start position each time.
If I will run a *:* 10 times while increment the start position by 10 each time can I assume I'll get all 100 docs or since there is no sorting each time I'll get a different random 10 documents.
I know that in SQL databases it worn't work, I was wondering if Solr is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr is different. In case that you do not specify a sort order, it will sort by score. In case the score is equal, it will sort by the moment a document got indexed.

In case that you query for `*:*` (MatchAllDocsQuery) all documents do have the same score and will be returned in the order they got indexed, as described in the SO question [How are results ordered in solr in a "match all docs" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310194/how-are-results-ordered-in-solr-in-a-match-all-docs-query)

When would the order change? In case one of the documents gets updated. Then it will fall behind its' older brothers.

But Solr has a [RandomSortField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html) for this matter:

> Utility Field used for random sorting. It should not be passed a value.
>
> This random sorting implementation uses the dynamic field name to set the random 'seed'. To get random sorting order, you need to use a random dynamic field name.