# In which order SOLR returns results if no keyword specified? For multiple Drupal content types

Tags: search, drupal, solr

There is Drupal installation which uses SOLR via apachesolr module. 
In which order are results sorted if I go just to search/site link?

Comment: Relevance of what? There are no keywords specified.

Comment: If you don't provide a query or a sort, the default is [to return the documents in the same order as they were added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310194/how-are-results-ordered-in-solr-in-a-match-all-docs-query).

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it is sorted by Node id.